# Javascript Array keys which holds sub-arrays

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have an array which holds sub-arrays, the main array has custom keys; used as an identifier. 
The problem is I can't access the array with these keys set e.g:

array.length - returns 0 when clearly it has values

**In console:**

> [evt1: Array[0], evt2: Array[0]]
>   
> evt1: Array[0]
>   
> evt2: Array[0]

When changed back to a standard index (0,1,2), the array can be accessed - and performs as normal. Why is this happening?

Thanks

Comment: Arrays dont have keys, they have indexes. Objects have keys, and each key of an object could contain an array.

Comment: @tymeJV To be picky, the arrays _are_ objects and they get a key/property for each index e.g. `[4,5,6].hasOwnProperty('1') //true`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As stated in comments, you are not using an array, you are using an object. Use `Object.keys(your_object).length` to get length, and to travel through indexes:

```
for(var index in your_object){
    console.log(index,your_object[index]);
}
```

You can also do:

```
var indexes=Object.keys(your_object);
for(var i=0;i<indexes.length;i++){
    console.log(indexes[i], your_object[indexes[i]]);
}
```

Comment: @Martin The for..in loop is used to iterate object properties in Javascript

Comment: I know that. But I've never seen this way of iterating over objects

Comment: @Martin Then what have you seen o.O

Comment: Ok I've seen the `for ... in` loops before (obviously) but I've never seen `Object.keys(your_object).length` to be used in a regular `for` loop. The answer was edited since my first comment

Answer (score 1):

Arrays (like many other things in javascript) can have properties just like objects, however, array properties do not count toward the length of the array. What you should use is an object as the outer structure that contains your keys->arrays.

```
{evt1: Array[0], evt2: Array[0]}
```